# Digging deeper into DOMElement

Tags: php, zend-framework, dom, zend-dom-query

I've used Zend_Dom_Query to extract some `<tr>` elements and I want to now loop through them and do some more. Each `<tr>` looks like this, so how can I print the title `Title 1` and the id of the second td `id=categ-113`?

```
<tr class="sometr">
  <th><a class="title">Title1</a></th>
  <td class="category" id="categ-113"></td>
  <td class="somename">Title 1 name</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: @rfausak Are you the one who downvoted my question

Comment: Yes - this question is unclear and not useful; you should post some code explaining what you have tried and why it doesn't work.

Comment: @rfausak It's unclear to you because you're not familiar with the zend api. Others will be fine. They know what I'm talking about.

Comment: [DOM is DOM.](http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-DOM-Level-1-19981001/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just play around with the results. I've never worked with it, but this is how far i got (and im kinda new to Zend myself):

```
$dom = new ZEnd_Dom_Query($html);
$res = $dom->query('.sometr');

foreach($res as $dom) {
  $a = $obj->getElementsByTagName('a');
  echo $a->item(0)->textContent; // the title
}
```

And with this i think you're set to go. For further information and functions to be used of the result look up DOMElement ( http://php.net/manual/de/class.domelement.php ). With this information you should be able to grab all that. But my question is:
Why doing this so complicated, i don't really see a use-case for doing this. As the title and everything else should be something coming from the database? And if it's an XML there's better solutions than relying on Dom_Query.

Anyways, if this was helpful to you please accept and/or vote the answer.